# Include another .s file on x86_64 assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, att

I'm writing x86_64 AT&T syntax assembly and compiling it with `gcc`. What I want to accomplish is having similar functions grouped in separate files. Unfortunately I can't find any information how to call function from another file. Simply compiling both files into one executable throws bunch of `undefined reference` errors.

I suspect solution to my problem is trivial, but I just can't find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In each file with a function you wish to export to other modules (make global) using `.global functionname` . To use a global symbol from another module use `.extern functionname`

Comment: GNU `as` [treats all undefined symbols as external](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Extern.html) so using `.extern` is optional.

Comment: Some additional info can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47563533/3857942

Comment: What worked for me was "#include external_file.s".

Comment: Oops, apologies, that should `.include "external_file.s"`